# Как сделать собственный вывод ошибок на этапе компиляции в C++?

Tags: c++

То есть необходимо при компиляции программы, вывести не стандартный код ошибки и ее описание, а свой текст, возможно ли это средствами самого С++?

Comment: написать свой компилятор? Или взять gcc/clang и допилить?

Comment: @KoVadim, это да, но была надежда, что можно как-то реализовать средствами языка, в любом случае, спасибо)

Comment: Боюсь, что это невозможно.

Comment: В зависимости от того, желаете ли вы получить ошибку на этапе препроцессинга или компиляции, вы можете [использовать `#error` или `static_assert`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633987/how-can-i-force-a-compile-error-in-c) Второй поддерживается только в C++11, поэтому для pre-C++11 компиляторов придется [использовать BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) с менее понятным сообщением об ошибке.

Comment: - Возможно, я неправильно понял вопрос, и вы на самом деле хотите сделать кастомное описание для каких-нибудь стандартных ошибок типа "missing semicolon". Тогда это действительно невозможно.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать (ну и имячко!) а если запустить g++ дочерним процессом и транслировать диагностические сообщения?

Comment: @alexlz: Это не поможет, если данную ошибку gcc не ловит (например, ТС хочет запретить конструкторы без параметров).

@Denis Neustroev: опишите вашу проблему поточнее: какого рода ошибки вы хотите обрабатывать и как? Может, приведите пример?

Comment: Может вам нужен assert?